# Why does AWS firewall not permit remote connection from my work computer?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I setup an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux AMI) to host a Docker API (Flask application with Python). The application is running on port 5000. Using my local PC (which is remote), I am able to hit the API with a browser (i.e., http://ipaddress:5000/), and get the "Hello, World!" response. The issue is that when I do the same thing on another computer (my work computer), I get a connection refused error.

In the security group for the instance, these are my inbound rule settings (I know this isn't secure, it's just a Hello World example):

HTTP (TCP): Port 80, allow 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0

SSH (TCP): Port 22, allow 0.0.0.0/0

Custom TCP Rule (TCP): Port 5000, 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0

The question: Why is the firewall blocking one remote computer and not the other?

Comment: and the outbound rules? all open ?

Comment: @andre_vieira, outbound rules: All traffic (All protocol): All port ranges,  
0.0.0.0/0

Comment: @andre-vieira - By outbound rules, I thought you were referring to those applicable to AWS (not the corporate network). Since you led me to thinking about outbound ports, I upvoted your response as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I has talking about aws rules. But good to know that you solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem**: Corporate firewalls will often set outbound rules that limit which ports you can access from websites outside of your organization.

**The solution**: Since Port 80 is a common port used for web servers, corporate firewalls (generally) don't block outbound traffic to these ports. Therefore, I was able to fix this problem by deploying the AWS API on Port 80. Then, I was able to connect to the API from within my corporate network.